# Cannot open port 1337

Tags: iptables, firewall, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I am struggling with iptables firewall to open port 1337 externally.
My iptables file looks like this:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1337 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [353:23420]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [246:30708]
COMMIT
```

Locally, I get my response. Remotely I don't.
I tried to `save`, `stop` and `start` iptables, but it does not fix my issue.

Comment: Centos version?

Comment: I am actually on EC2: "$ cat /etc/*elease" produces:
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2015.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2015.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2015.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2015.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2015.03

Comment: Ok a EC2 instance, you need add the rule to the Security Group, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule

Comment: This "firewall" doesn't actually block anything anyway. It has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @Manu did you find your answer?

Comment: Yes, just verified it was enough to set up a security groups. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Federico is right. AWS has security groups assigned to each EC2 instance. These can be set to protocols or custom port/port ranges and set to allow your IP, custom IP or all. It'll always require a CIDR value if I recall, but if it's just you it'll tack on a /32 at the end of your IP address. Go to your main dashboard, locate the line that has your instance, and click on the security group to navigate to it.

If this doesn't work please provide a traceroute.

Example of what a security group (not yours per-se) looks like: [image: here's a so-so example of what a security group looks like]